# Spring XD: "tcp" source outputs byte array instead of string? How to output regular text?

Tags: spring-xd

The goal is to read data emitted over the network.

On the data generation side I have an app which spews to stdout.  The content of this data is a JSON string.

Here's what I'm doing (on Linux Mint 17, using an BSD flavored netcat):

*data generation:*

```
my_app_which_outputs_json | netcat localhost 9999
```

*In SpringXD:* (with `xd-singlenode`)

```
xd:>stream create --name tcptest --definition "tcp --decoder=LF --port=9999 | file " --deploy
Created and deployed new stream 'tcptest'
```

*Output:*

```
/tmp/xd/output$ cat tcptest.out 
82,117,110, ...  (etc, lots more bytes)
```

I'm sure this is user error, but not sure what to change to make it right.

I should note that if I do this, it works as expected:

```
my_app_which_outputs_json > /tmp/somefile.txt
...
xd:>stream create --name filetest --definition "tail --name=/tmp/somefile.txt | file" --deploy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following to my stream defn and it is now doing what I expected.  I found this in the "Type Conversion" section of the documentation.

```
stream create --name tcptest \
    --definition "tcp --decoder=LF --port=9999 --outputType=text/plain \
    | file " --deploy
```

(The newlines and backwhacks are not in my actual code, but are used for readability.)

I also tried `... --outputType=application/json...` which did not work.  Not entirely sure why.

Answer (score 2):

Following up to your own answer, the converters are currently not configured to understand that a `byte[]` can be converted to a String with content type `application/json`.

Of course, even if we configured it to do so, it wouldn't be able to determine if the content really is JSON.

Answer (score 1):

text/plain with a byte[] payload activates a ByteArrayToStringMessageConverter. application/json does not currently. I have created https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-2512 to address this